# What is the best way to analyze progression with low n?

Tags: data-visualization, mean, repeated-measures

I have been assigned a task at my job where I am supposed to analyze the progression in well being in a group of children. However, I usually only work with qualitative data and therefore I have no experience with this kind of work. I also can't ask anyone at my job, because the only employee, who knows how to do this kind of work, is off sick.

Over the last year and a half a group of children have 3 times been asked a series of questions about their well being (on a scale from 1 to 5), and now I am going to analyze if their well being has enhanced. There have been quite a lot of drop outs and only 26 children have answered all 3 "tests". I have therefore eliminated any child who haven't participated in all three "tests", and I have also been been told that I am not going to do any regressions. I am however not sure how I should conduct the analysis.

I have considered to calculate the mean of the group for each time period and then display the means in a line chart or a scatter plot with a trend line. I have tried to show an example of my own thoughts below. The x-axis is showing the time periods and the y-axis is showing the mean score in well being.

Is this the correct approach? If not what would you recommend that I do?

[image]
[image: Line chart] [image: scatter plot with trend line]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Unfortunately, I think your best bet is either to wait for your colleague to return or to hire a consultant.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate a bit? Are you saying that my suggestion is totally wrong?

Comment: Your graph is fine, but if you want to do formal analyses, I think you'll need a multilevel model, and those are pretty complex.